# How can I use video in raw folder instead of the the videoUrl

Tags: android, kotlin

**VideoModel:**
Project video model is here,

```
data class VideoModel(
    var videoTitle:String,
    var videoDesc:String,
    var videoUrl:String)
```

and I have video url below, but I want to use the video in raw folder instead of the url, is it possible?

```
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        arrVideoModel.add(VideoModel("Tree with flowers","The branches of a tree wave in the breeze, with pointy leaves ","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mncFy1H7OUM"))
   
        videoAdapter = VideoAdapter(arrVideoModel)
        viewPager.adapter = videoAdapter

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use a video from `raw` folder using `ExoPlayer's` [RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri()](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/RawResourceDataSource.html) method.

Here is a sample I have used to achieve the same:

> Add the ExoPlayer dependency in your `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.14.1'
```

> Get the Uri by using `RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri()`

```
val videoUri: Uri = RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(R.raw.video_name)
arrVideoModel.add(VideoModel("Tree with flowers","The branches of a tree wave in the breeze, with pointy leaves ", videoUri.toString()))
```

This will give you Uri of the video you have added in the `raw` folder.

Comment: can u update according to question if possible? thx